# SharePoint Permisison was deleted on SP library, how will I restore it?

Tags: sharepoint

I accidentally deleted all permissions on SP library including the owner.  Now, I cant assigned permission to that library nor I can see it in Site Contents. And by the way, I am the site Admin and Site Collection Admin but cant figure out to restore permission to that library.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate though it is, the short answer to your question is **NO**. I' m afraid there is no door opened for you to restore the deleted permission except recreating it unless you have back up.

Comment: Thanks Allen.  I guess I have to recreate that library then.